# Como preencher dois formArraym um dentro do outro

Tags: javascript, angular

Boa tarde!!!

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para conseguir preencher dois form Array, um dentro do outro, estou fazendo mais ou menos assim:

```js
  dadosBeneficiarioForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    nome: [null],
    valorTotalAutorizado: [null],
    planoAssistencialSaude: this.fb.array([
      {
        dependentes: this.fb.array([])
      }
    ])
  });

// function para adicionar os no fromArray
this.beneficioService.getDependentes().subscribe((response) => {

      response.forEach((planoAssistencialSaude) => {

        this.addPlanoAssistencial(planoAssistencialSaude);

        this.addDependente(planoAssistencialSaude.titular);

      });

    });


  addDependente(dependente: DependenteBeneficiario) {
    const dependForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [dependente.id, Validators.required],
      nome: [dependente.nome, Validators.required],
      valor: [dependente.valor, Validators.required],
      tipo: [dependente.tipo, Validators.required]
    });

    this.dependentes.push(dependForm);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu caso você está querendo criar um array de objetos, onde cada objeto possui um atributo chamado `dependentes` sendo este um outro array. Portanto na criação do formulário, se você deseja já inicial um plano com um array de pendentes, você deve passar um outro `FormGroup` dentro de `planoAssistencialSaude`, ficando assim.

```
criarFormulario() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nome: [null],
      valorTotalAutorizado: [null],
      planoAssistencialSaude: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          dependentes: this.fb.array([])
        })
      ])
    });
  }
```

Agora, para adicionar novos objetos no seu array, você deve procurar o plano pelo índice do array, aí sim você pode adicionar no array de dependentes.

[Eu fiz um exemplo no stackblitz para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5flzyw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Uma forma de você resolver isso é criando separadamente os arrays. Primeiro, declare um `FormArray` dentro da classe, fora do `FormGroup` original, para os dependentes. Depois, tu adiciona todos os elementos nesse array antes de inseri-lo ao `control` no `FormGroup`

```js
dadosBeneficiarioForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    nome: [null],
    valorTotalAutorizado: [null],
    planoAssistencialSaude: this.fb.array([])
  });
  dependentesForm = new FormArray([]);


  addDependente(dependente){
    const dependForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [d.id, Validators.required],
        nome: [d.nome, Validators.required],
        valor: [d.valor, Validators.required],
        tipo: [d.tipo, Validators.required]
      });
      this.dependentesForm.push(dependForm);
  }
```

Depois, pode chamar o control  `planoAssistencialSaude` como um `FormArray` e realizar o push do dependentesForm

```js
 const plano = this.dadosBeneficiarioForm.controls
      .planoAssistencialSaude as FormArray;
    plano.push(this.dependentesForm);
```

Criei um stackblitz utilizando uma abordagem um pouco mais completa, onde tu cria um array de dependentes e ao final, em algum tipo de submit que vá usar, crie os `FormGroups` para cada dependente, insira no `FormArray` e depois no control adequado. Recomendo essa abordagem por haver a possibilidade de você adicionar novos dependentes por meio da sua UI. Assim, a cada nova entrada você insere nesse array e apenas ao final insere no FormArray.

Segue o [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxt4eg?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)